# register .net 2.0 dll into gac 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, gac

It is possible to load .NET 2.0 dll into CLR 4.0 using `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy`.

Now is it possible to install an assembly compiled with .NET 2.0 into GAC for CLR 4.0 without recompiling?

CLR 2.0 gac = C:\Windows\assembly

CLR 4.0 gac = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly

Comment: Hard to see the point, just keep it in the 2.0 GAC.  A 4.x program has no trouble finding it there.

Comment: The goal is to use 2 sets of incompatible DLLs registered in GAC2 and GAC4 with some shared DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to decompile using free dotPeek or ILSpy, export as solution and recompile in VS Express 2013+ with target to .NET 4.0+